# Laptop Lags for Few Seconds After Startup

Tags: wireless-networking, boot, operating-systems, windows-11, lag

Following are the specifications of my laptop:

Processor:  AMD Ryzen 7 5800H with Radeon Graphics            3.20 GHz 
Installed RAM:  16.0 GB (15.3 GB usable) 
System type:    64-bit operating system, x64-based processor 
OS: Windows 11 Home Single Language 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Laptop GPU

From some time, I have been observing a strange lag issue in my laptop which I believe should not be the case with the specifications I have listed above. The moment after starting up, my laptop starts lagging, the cursor kind of drags over the screen instead of moving smoothly, clicking and moving the cursor become difficult, this continues for around 20 seconds or so.

Initially I tried ignoring this but then it became too annoying to be ignored. Since I have dual boot (the issue existed even before I set up dual boot so dual boot is not the root cause), I tend to do a lot of work on Ubuntu and face no issues there, so it doesn't seem to be a hardware issue. Also, I have noticed that this issue occurs while connecting to Wi-Fi at the beginning, though I could be wrong, but it seems it has something to do with Wi-Fi.

Resetting the PC doesn't seem feasible to me at the moment. It would be great to know if anyone of you have previously solved this problem successfully and how you did it.

The thing is I tried looking up this issue on the internet, and I did find a few suggestions. One was to uninstall and then reinstall the mouse driver. I tried it but that did not fix the problem. Another was to disable "fast startup", I did that but still no improvement. Then I put my laptop on Performance Mode, even that didn't help.

I could have tried monitoring the task manager for suspicious processes, but it seems impossible with so many processes running at the same time which makes it difficult to spot one out. I tried checking for malware, didn't find any. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Spotting the faulty process(es), if any, in the task manager is the first to try. And no it's not difficult, you just have to sort them according to the CPU usage, RAM usage, etc.., by clicking at the top of the appropriate column.

Comment: It seems like a software problem and reinstalling Windows is likely the fastest way to solve the issue.  Do run a complete set of Manufacturer's Diagnostics.  Do update all drivers including BIOS (UEFI)